# Which of these is better to use when creating a Class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

I am currently practicing OO javascript and came upon some different ways to create a Class of sorts in Javascript.

These are:

```
var Classname = function() {
  var that = {
    functionone: function(arg) {
      return value;
    },
    functiontwo: function() {
      return value;
    }
  };
  return that;
}
var foo = ClassName();
```

And:

```
var ClassName = function() {
  return this;
};
ClassName.fn = ClassName.prototype = {
  constructor: ClassName,
  variables: values,
  functionone: function(args) {
    return value;
  },
  functiontwo: function() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

I have used both in a small thing I was practicing with, but I used the latter for a local object storage, meaning it wasn't used to create new instances of itself, but just a single instance that would expand itself with new objects.

Is there a big difference between either and do they either both serve a specific purpose or is it better to use the first or second?

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I could not find something similar to this question of either a comparison and asking which would be preferrable.

Comment: The question was flagged as duplicate, does this mean that the first of these two examples I gave is like the prototype way given in the question mine is a duplicate of? I haven't used the word prototype anywhere.

Comment: Take a look at your second code snippet: `ClassName.prototype = …` :-)

Comment: Notice though that your first isn't a "constructor" in the classical sense, it's more like a *factory*. Inheritance is done very different with that scheme.

Comment: In fact you should use neither of the patterns if you only create a single instance. Use the module pattern, or a simple object literal.

Comment: Ah... I see... I hadn't even noticed that... I'll check out the other question that this is a duplicate of. Sorry...